# How to make url validation without http ( or add it after validation passed )?

Tags: url, jquery-validate

I can't make my custom url validation rule work.

I'm adding new rule:

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("complete_url", function(val, elem) {
// if no url, don't do anything
  return  /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/.test(val);
    });
 ...
 $("#new_website").validate({
    rules: {
          url: "complete_url",
         'website[url]': {
            url: true,
            required: true}
           }
        });
```

but it returns me

```
   invalid URL
```

I checked Regex here - http://www.rubular.com/. It is working, but failing it my custom validator.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7):

Please don't use regexes for this. Don't even use the same regex that the jQuery validator uses, it may change in the future and you won't be able to take advantage of the updates. This is the way to do this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('validUrl', function(value, element) {
        var url = $.validator.methods.url.bind(this);
        return url(value, element) || url('http://' + value, element);
    }, 'Please enter a valid URL');
```

Comment: This is a much better way of achieving the desired result, props for thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 3):

I used this and it works well

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("url2", function(value, element, param) {
return this.optional(element) || /^(www\.)(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)*(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(value);
}, jQuery.validator.messages.url);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkurl", function(value, element) {
// now check if valid url
return /^(www\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid URL."
);

 // connect it to a css class
  jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
checkurl : { checkurl : true }    
 });
  ...
    'website[url]': {
            checkurl: true
    }
```

Comment: What is this? Is it a working answer? I'm looking for a solution to the same problem.