# jQuery validate URL without http://

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a url without http:// using jQuery validate but it's not working. I am following the mtosic's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741517/how-to-make-url-validation-without-http-or-add-it-after-validation-passed)

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

  $.validator.addMethod('validUrl', function(value, element) {
    var url = $.validator.methods.url.bind(this);
    return url(value, element) || url('http://' + value, element);
  }, 'Please enter a valid URL');

$("#form").validate({
  rules: {
    "url": {
      url: "validUrl"
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function (form) { 
    alert('valid form submitted'); 
    return false; 
  }
});
```

When I type in an address like "www.google.com" I still get the invalid error.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2wrv3cg/)

What is the issue? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you've defined the rule named `validUrl`, yet you're still setting the `url` rule on the element in the `$.validate` settings. Also note that you want to pass a boolean value to the property, not a string. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod('validUrl', function(value, element) {
    var url = $.validator.methods.url.bind(this);
    return url(value, element) || url('http://' + value, element);
  }, 'Please enter a valid URL');

  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      "url": {
        validUrl: true // <-- change this
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
      return false; // for demo
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

input.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

label.error {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: red;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it perfectly works thanks @Rory